# What is the importance of the question mark and what is the benefit of this code?

Tags: typescript

```
function nanogegreee(num7, isInteger) {
    if (isInteger === void 0) {
        isInteger = false;
    }
    return Math.floor(num7 * num7);
}

console.log(nanogegreee(4.6));
```

Comment: What question mark? Also, isInteger doesn't appear to serve any purpose. And please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as a TypeScript question, if by question mark, you are referring to interface construction or parameters, the question mark after the parameter means that it can be omitted from an object instantiation (if in an interface) or a function call (if a parameter in a function).

As far as the code, please be more specific in your question.